# Need help debugging this code. It only returns undefined for the normal string. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

How come it doesn't return everything. Don't I need to use toString to convert the numbers into strings?
Output:
[
'Normal: 63',
'Tachycardia: 117',
'Bradycardia: 52',
'Tachycardia: 121',
'Normal: 67',
'Bradycardia: 43'
]

```
function diagnoseRates(data) {

    var patients = [];
    var lowHR = 'Bradycardia: ';
    var highHR = 'Tachycardia: ';
    var currentPatient = data[i];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if (currentPatient < 60) {
            patients.push(lowHR + currentPatient.toString());
        } else if (currentPatient > 100) {
            patients.push(highHR + currentPatient.toString());
        } else patients.push('Normal: ' + currentPatient.toString());
    }
    return patients;
}
```

Comment: ```var currentPatient = data[i];```  should be inside the for loop

Comment: This code won't run as written due to the syntax error.

Comment: Can you show `data` you are passing into the function call?

Comment: No need for toString(), as when we can use + operator to concatenate a string to a number since the left operand is string, operator is + and right operand is number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if you are passing different data than I assumed

```js
var arr = [67,114,52,141,67,43]
console.log(diagnoseRates(arr));

function diagnoseRates(data) {

var patients = [];
var lowHR = 'Bradycardia: ';
var highHR = 'Tachycardia: ';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var currentPatient = data[i];
    if (currentPatient < 60) {
        patients.push(lowHR + currentPatient);
    } else if (currentPatient > 100) {
        patients.push(highHR + currentPatient);
    } else patients.push('Normal: ' + currentPatient);
}
return patients.join(','); // IF YOU WANT DATA TO BE JOIN WITH COMMA
// return patients; // IF YOU WANT DATA TO BE RETURNED AS AN ARRAY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Function will return an error.
Because, `var currentPatient = data[i]`, `i` is not define, so `currentPatient` is undefined too.